# recursively print n, n-1, n-2,...3,2,1,2,3,...n

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Hello I have a homework question I am stuck in..any hint or tips would be appreciated. the questions is:

Write a single recursive function in C++ that takes as argument a positive integer `n` then print `n, n-1, n-2,...3,2,1,2,3,...n`. How many recursive call does your algorithm makes? What is the worst case running time of your algorithm?

I am stuck in the first part. writing a recursive function that prints `n, n-1, n-2,...3,2,1,2,3,...n`

so far I have:

```
print(int n)
{
    if (n==0)
    return;
    cout<<n<<" ";
    print(n-1);

return;
}
```

but this only prints from `n` to `1`
I am lost about how I would print from `2` to `n` using just one parameter and recursively single function.

I tried this: which gives the correct output but has a loop and has two parameters:

```
p and z has the same value. 

void print(int p,int z)
{

if (p==0)
    {
        for(int x=2;x<=z; x++)
            cout<<x<<" ";
        return;
    }
    else

    cout<<p<<" ";
    print(p-1,z);

return;
}
```

any hint or tips is much appreciated thank you.

so it is working now, but I am having trouble understanding how (question in comment):

```
void print(int n)
{

if (n==1){
    cout<<n;
    return;
    }
else
    cout<< n;
    print(n-1); // how does it get passed this? to the line below?
    cout<<n;    // print(n-1) takes it back to the top?
return;
}
```

Comment: HINT: The recusive function has to "wind", then "unwind". Print something in both cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The output you want is mirrored, so you can have this series of steps:

```
print num
recursive step on num-1
print num again
```

That's the recursive case. Now you need an appropriate base case upon which to stop the recursion, which shouldn't be difficult.

---

Given the pseudocode:

```
recursive_print(n):
    if n == 1:
        print 1
        return

    print n
    recursive_print(n-1)
    print n
```

(If you prefer, just look at your solution instead).

Let's trace it. A dot will mark where we're up to in terms of printing.

```
. recursive_print(3)    // Haven't printed anything
3 . recursive_print(2) 3    // Print the 3
3 2 . recursive_print(1) 2 3    //Print 2
3 2 1 . 2 3         // Print 1
3 2 1 2 . 3         // Print 2
3 2 1 2 3 .         // Print 3
```

Each unrolling of the function gives us 2 numbers on opposite sides and we build down to the "1", then go back and print the rest of the numbers.

---

The "unrolling" is shown in this picture:
[image]

If you strip away the functions and leave yourself with a sequence of commands, you'll get:

```
print 3
    print 2
        print 1
    print 2
print 3
```

where each indentation signifies a different function.

Comment: should the base case be n == 1?

Comment: @EK7 You have a compiler, try it out (or better, trace it on paper). If it doesn't work, change and repeat.

Comment: it WORKED!!!!! omg I've been sitting here past 5 hours trying to do that. Thank YOU!

Comment: @EK7 Your request for an explanation appears to be gone, but I edited the answer with an attempt to explain it.

Comment: I understanding why it prints up to 1...after that where does the 2 and 3 print from? which line is responsible for printing the 2 and 3?

Comment: @EK7 Is http://i.imgur.com/4NTugvf.png helpful? Every function (except 1) displays its number twice: once before calling print(n-1) and once after. When print(1) is done, control returns to print(2) and the next thing it does it display "2". It then returns control back to print(3), which then displays "3".

Comment: edited again; included pic and sequential series of `print`s.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for this:

```
Def fxn(n):
    if n <= n: 
        if n > 0:
            print(n)
            fxn(n - 1)
            print(n)


Def main():
    Number = 6
    fxn(Number)

Main()
```

If you struggle understanding how this works:

Basically, each time you call a function in a recursive problem, it isn't a loop. It's as if you were on the woods leaving a trail behind. Each time you call a function inside a function, it does its thing, then it goes right back to were you called it.

In other words, whenever you call a recursive function, once the newer attempt is done, it will go right back to were it used to be.

In loops, once each step is done, it is done, but in recursive functions you can do a lot with a lot less.

Printing before the recurse call in my code is the descension step, and once its descension finished, it will progresively unfold step by step, printing the ascension value and going back to the former recurse.

It seems way harder than it is, but it is really easy once you grasp it.

Comment: Im new to this web Page so i dont get why it all got compressed... still, press enter a couple times and run it and youll realize. Sorry for the inconvenience though!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simpler than you think.

A recursive call is no different from a regular call. The only difference is that the function called is also the caller, so you need to make sure you don't call it forever (you already did that). Let's think about a regular call. If you have the following code snippet:

```
statement1
f();
statement2
```

The statement1 is executed, then f is called and does it's thing and then, after f finishes, statement2 is executed.

Now, let's think about your problem. I can see that your hard work on this question from the second program you've written, but forget about it, the first one is very close to the answer.

Let's think about what your function does. It prints all numbers from n to 0 and then from 0 to n. At the first step, you want to print n, then all the numbers from n-1 to 0 and from 0 to n-1, and print another n. See where it's going?

So, you have to do something like this:

```
print(n)
call f(n-1)
print(n)
```

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of hack -- using the std::stream rather than recursion...

```
void rec(int n) {
    if (n==1) { cout << 1; return; }
    cout << n;
    rec(n-1);
    cout << n;
}

int main() {
    rec(3);
}
```

prints

```
32123
```

Comment: Why do you say this has no recursion?

Comment: mistake -- I wanted to say that you need some ambient structure to do this but what I said was just stupid